# How to set mid-roll dynamically in Google IMA (VMAP)

Tags: vast, double-click-advertising

I'm using using Google IMA test tags (https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/tags) in my video player successfully. We are focused on using VMAP as our video player (VideoJS) does not have an ad scheduler.

Now I'm interested in implementing mid-roll. I can implement the test mid-roll tags just fine which have a static mid-roll value. The issue is that I would like to set my mid-roll points dynamically so each video can have mid-rolls in different places. For example, VideoA would have a mid-roll at 30 seconds. VideoB at 47 seconds and so on.

How can I adjust where the mid-rolls happen when calling my IMA tag? It seems these are static values.

Thank you!

Comment: You can manage time to play ad with `autoPlayAdBreaks: false`, but it keeps serving ads based on that VAST fixed value. So until you reach that time, it cannot be playd. Basically you can only delay ad playback from moment when ad is scheduled..

Comment: Not sure I understand. I'm also having a pre-roll and multiple mid-rolls. Unless I am misunderstanding, I don't believe this approach will work.

Comment: It is part of videojs-ima documentation..

Comment: Yes I know autoPlayAdBreaks: false is in the documentation. I'm just not sure how this would be used to set multiple mid-rolls and have them in different spots depending on the video that is playing

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No I don't believe so